# modify walker_comment to show/hide comment_text

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to show / hide the comment_text under the comment_meta for a custom post type, editing the walker_class of the twenty twenty theme (child).
I succeeded in doing it with javascript but it works only on the first comment!

What's wrong?
Either trying to pass the comment_id like the div_id, it doesn't work at all.

It's about 2days I've spent round here!

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom comment walker for this theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

if ( ! class_exists( 'TwentyTwenty_Walker_Comment' ) ) {
    /**
     * CUSTOM COMMENT WALKER
     * A custom walker for comments, based on the walker in Twenty Nineteen.
     */
    class TwentyTwenty_Walker_Comment extends Walker_Comment {
        /**
         * Outputs a comment in the HTML5 format.
         *
         * @see wp_list_comments()
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author_url/
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author/
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_reply_link/
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_comment_link/
         *
         * @param WP_Comment $comment Comment to display.
         * @param int        $depth   Depth of the current comment.
         * @param array      $args    An array of arguments.
         */
        protected function html5_comment( $comment, $depth, $args ) {

            $tag = ( 'div' === $args['style'] ) ? 'div' : 'li';
            ?>
            <<?php echo $tag; //phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped -- static output ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class( $this->has_children ? 'parent' : '', $comment ); ?>>
                <article id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment-body">

                    <footer class="comment-meta">
                        <div class="comment-author vcard" onclick="showDiv()" >
                            <?php
                            $comment_author_url = get_comment_author_url( $comment );
                            $comment_author     = get_comment_author( $comment );
                            $avatar             = get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] );
                            $comme              = get_comment_text( $comment );
                            $id_com             = get_comment_id( $comment );
                            if ( 0 !== $args['avatar_size'] ) {
                                if ( empty( $comment_author_url ) ) {
                                    echo wp_kses_post( $avatar );
                                } else {
                                    printf( '<a href="%s" rel="external nofollow" class="url">', $comment_author_url ); //phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped --Escaped in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author_url/
                                    echo wp_kses_post( $avatar );
                                }
                            }

                            printf(
                                '<span class="fn">%1$s</span><span class="screen-reader-text says">%2$s</span>',
                                esc_html( $comment_author ),
                                __( 'says:', 'twentytwenty' )
                            );

                            if ( ! empty( $comment_author_url ) ) {
                                echo '</a>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- .comment-author -->

                        <div class="comment-metadata">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment, $args ) ); ?>">
                                <?php
                                /* Translators: 1 = comment date, 2 = comment time */
                                $comment_timestamp = sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentytwenty' ), get_comment_date( '', $comment ), get_comment_time() );
                                ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php comment_time( 'c' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $comment_timestamp ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( $comment_timestamp ); ?>
                                </time>
                            </a>
                            <?php
                            if ( get_edit_comment_link() ) {
                                echo ' <span aria-hidden="true">&bull;</span> <a class="comment-edit-link" href="' . esc_url( get_edit_comment_link() ) . '">' . __( 'Edit', 'twentytwenty' ) . '</a>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

                    </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

                    <!--- <div class="comment-content entry-content"> -->

                    <div class="comment-content entry-content" id="<?php echo $id_com ;?>" >
                    <?php
                        echo $comme;
                        if ( '0' === $comment->comment_approved ) {
                            ?>
                            <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'twentytwenty' ); ?></p>

                            <?php
                        }
                     ?></div>
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                            function showDiv() {
                                var id_com = <?php echo $id_com ;?>;  //retrieving the id
                                if (document.getElementById(id_com).style.display == 'none') {
                                    document.getElementById(id_com).style.display = 'block';
                                } else {
                                    document.getElementById(id_com).style.display = 'none';
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
                    <!-- </div><!-- .comment-content -->


                    <?php

                    $comment_reply_link = get_comment_reply_link(
                        array_merge(
                            $args,
                            array(
                                'add_below' => 'div-comment',
                                'depth'     => $depth,
                                'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
                                'before'    => '<span class="comment-reply">',
                                'after'     => '</span>',
                            )
                        )
                    );

                    $by_post_author = twentytwenty_is_comment_by_post_author( $comment );

                    if ( $comment_reply_link || $by_post_author ) {
                        ?>

                        <footer class="comment-footer-meta">


                            <?php
                            if ( $comment_reply_link ) {
                                echo $comment_reply_link; //phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped --Link is escaped in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_reply_link/
                            }
                            if ( $by_post_author ) {
                                echo '<span class="by-post-author">' . __( 'By Post Author', 'twentytwenty' ) . '</span>';
                            }
                            ?>

                        </footer>

                        <?php
                    ;}
                    ?>

                </article><!-- .comment-body -->

            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeed in solving the problem:
the javascript function needed to have a different name for each comment, same for the container to hide/show

That's the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom comment walker for this theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

if ( ! class_exists( 'TwentyTwenty_Walker_Comment' ) ) {
    /**
     * CUSTOM COMMENT WALKER
     * A custom walker for comments, based on the walker in Twenty Nineteen.
     */
    class TwentyTwenty_Walker_Comment extends Walker_Comment {
        /**
         * Outputs a comment in the HTML5 format.
         *
         * @see wp_list_comments()
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author_url/
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author/
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_reply_link/
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_comment_link/
         *
         * @param WP_Comment $comment Comment to display.
         * @param int        $depth   Depth of the current comment.
         * @param array      $args    An array of arguments.
         */
        protected function html5_comment( $comment, $depth, $args ) {

            $tag = ( 'div' === $args['style'] ) ? 'div' : 'li';
            ?>
            <<?php echo $tag; //phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped -- static output ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class( $this->has_children ? 'parent' : '', $comment ); ?>>
                <article id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment-body">

                    <footer class="comment-meta">
                        <div class="comment-author vcard" onclick="showDiv<?php echo get_comment_id(); ?>()" >
                            <?php
                            $comment_author_url = get_comment_author_url( $comment );
                            $comment_author     = get_comment_author( $comment );
                            $avatar             = get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] );
                            $comme              = get_comment_text( $comment );
                            $id_com             = get_comment_id( $comment );
                            if ( 0 !== $args['avatar_size'] ) {
                                if ( empty( $comment_author_url ) ) {
                                    echo wp_kses_post( $avatar );
                                } else {
                                    printf( '<a href="%s" rel="external nofollow" class="url">', $comment_author_url ); //phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped --Escaped in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author_url/
                                    echo wp_kses_post( $avatar );
                                }
                            }

                            printf(
                                '<span class="fn">%1$s</span><span class="screen-reader-text says">%2$s</span>',
                                esc_html( $comment_author ),
                                __( 'says:', 'twentytwenty' )
                            );

                            if ( ! empty( $comment_author_url ) ) {
                                echo '</a>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- .comment-author -->

                        <div class="comment-metadata">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment, $args ) ); ?>">
                                <?php
                                /* Translators: 1 = comment date, 2 = comment time */
                                $comment_timestamp = sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentytwenty' ), get_comment_date( '', $comment ), get_comment_time() );
                                ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php comment_time( 'c' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $comment_timestamp ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( $comment_timestamp ); ?>
                                </time>
                            </a>
                            <?php
                            if ( get_edit_comment_link() ) {
                                echo ' <span aria-hidden="true">&bull;</span> <a class="comment-edit-link" href="' . esc_url( get_edit_comment_link() ) . '">' . __( 'Edit', 'twentytwenty' ) . '</a>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

                    </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

                    <div id="<?php echo get_comment_id(); ?>" style=display:none>

                        <div class="comment-content entry-content">
                        <?php
                        echo $comme;
                        if ( '0' === $comment->comment_approved ) {
                            ?>
                            <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'twentytwenty' ); ?></p>

                            <?php
                        }
                        ?></div>
                        <?php

                        $comment_reply_link = get_comment_reply_link(
                            array_merge(
                                $args,
                                array(
                                    'add_below' => 'div-comment',
                                    'depth'     => $depth,
                                    'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
                                    'before'    => '<span class="comment-reply">',
                                    'after'     => '</span>',
                                )
                            )
                        );

                        $by_post_author = twentytwenty_is_comment_by_post_author( $comment );

                        if ( $comment_reply_link || $by_post_author ) {
                        ?>

                            <footer class="comment-footer-meta">

                            <?php
                            if ( $comment_reply_link ) {
                                echo $comment_reply_link; //phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped --Link is escaped in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_reply_link/
                            }
                            if ( $by_post_author ) {
                                echo '<span class="by-post-author">' . __( 'By Post Author', 'twentytwenty' ) . '</span>';
                            }
                            ?>

                            </footer>

                        <?php
                        ;}
                        ?>
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                            function showDiv<?php echo get_comment_id(); ?>() {
                                var id_com = <?php echo $id_com ;?>;  //retrieving the id
                                if (document.getElementById(id_com).style.display == 'none') {
                                    document.getElementById(id_com).style.display = 'block';
                                } else {
                                    document.getElementById(id_com).style.display = 'none';
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
                    </div><!-- il mio div -->

                </article><!-- .comment-body -->

            <?php
        }
    }
}
```